# Reject mail based on FROM domain

Tags: sieve

I'm wondering if it's possible to setup filter in sieve to catch the FROM domain and match that with the TO recipient mailbox name.

Usage is to filter unwanted emails when companies sell/share my personal information.

ex.

This should be accepted:

```
FROM: no-reply@some-company.com
TO: some-company@mydomain.com
```

This should be rejected:

```
FROM: no-reply@other-company.com
TO: some-company@mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need "allof" operator, which is boolean "and" for several tests. Something like this:

```
require ["fileinto", "mailbox"];
if allof
    (
        address "To" "some-company@mydomain.com",
        address "From" "no-reply@other-company.com"
    )
{
     fileinto "INBOX.Trash";
}
```

Notice, it is **bad** idea to reject on this stage, because it will generate a bounce and this is often not desired. The mail is already accepted by the time it is given to Sieve, so you can move it to spam or to trash, discard (silently delete) and so on, but don't reject.

Also notice that "To" and "From" headers from the mail can easily be forged. I'll be able to circumvent this filter by setting correct envelope address and faking the "To" header inside the mail to something other. It is *envelope* address (specified in the SMTP "RCPT To" command rather than the message header) controls which mailbox the mail gets delivered into. To test against envelope addresses, use the word "envelope" instead of "address" in the test, and also require "envelope" Sieve module.

See for example [here](https://support.tigertech.net/sieve) for details.

Comment: Alright cool, thanks for the reponse! 
do you know if it's possible to actually catch/split the origin sender domain into a variable to be used to match the destination mailbox name? meaning, to have it more dynamic and not static.

Comment: Did you try any research [by yourself](https://bfy.tw/T8th)?

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer, I personally like to use the action of:

{ reject "User email address rejected"; stop; }

You will probably need to include:

require "reject";

at the top of your sieve file.

I especially like this because:

1. It sends back an email rejection notice from the postmaster address, making it look as if the destination address is wrong.
2. The wording is such that it's ambiguous as to whether there's a probably with the actual address or if the user somehow rejected it.

Either way, the message is destroyed and never reaches your inbox at all!